# Highlight div element by darkening everything around it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to highlite a **relativ positioned** div element from a layer below, by making everything around it darker.

What I have tried:

- Copy the position of the original element, and the element itself and then insert that element at the copied position
- Construct the darker layer out of 4 rectangles so that this creates a negative rectangle, where the heart element I want to highlight shines through (picture 2)

Has anyone a really smart idea of how to achieve this? Both solutions, kind of work, but are really prone to errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try adding z index ?

Comment: The dark layer and the div i want to highlight are not in the same div.